# Overriding methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, methods, overriding

I'm currently learning C# by myself after studying Java for an entire semester.

One of the features of java (or object-oriented programming in general) is the ability to override methods that are inherited into a subclass.

When I was studying this feature in C#, I tried to override a method by myself without studying the proper way to override methods in C# and it seemed like it worked.

However, upon further study, I learned that we need to use the keyword `virtual` when declaring the method in the superclass and `override` when overriding the method in the subclass.

**So my question is:** 
What is the correct way to override methods in C#?

**Additional note:** I'm also wondering if the same case applies to overloading methods in C#.

Comment: The `virtual` keyword means "This a default implementation that can be overriden". The `abstract` keyword means "This must be overriden always". For obvious reasons you cannot use `abstract` if the class is not `abstract` also. The correct way depends on what do you need.

Comment: I couldn't find a direct question for this on Stackoverflow, I was about to answer.

Comment: @CodeNameJack There [are some](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+abstract+modifier), none of them very voted. Guess most of the questions get comments linking to microsoft language reference instead.

Comment: I would suggest checking [virual keyword reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) and looking at its restrictions, that would give you a good base on how/when to override.

Comment: I would suggest [override modifier C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) - everything about how to override is said there

Comment: @SirRufo That doesnt explain virtual modifier, I have added an answer with not only override, but also the rest of the inheritance modifiers and a sample

Comment: In Java, methods are `virtual` by default, unless specified as `final`. In C# they are "final"  (`sealed`) by default, unless specifically specified as `virtual`

Comment: @GamesWerfer - Could you explain what your 2nd question is about (overloading in C#): What is it you want to know about overloading methods? I think it is pretty straightforward in C#: You have multiple methods with the same scope, modifiers and method name but different signatures (parameters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different ways to override in .net depending on if you want to provide a default implementation or not.

- The [virtual keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) does provide a default implementation.
- The [abstract keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) does only declare what it must be overriden from those classes that inherit that class. It can only be used inside `abstract` classes.

There are other inheritance related keywords like:

- The [sealed keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) says that class is final, it cannot be inherited.
- The [override keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) It says that element is overriding a parent `abstract` or `virtual` element.

Example:

```
public abstract class Bank
{
    public abstract string Country { get; } // Everything inheriting must implement it
    public virtual decimal TaxPercent { get { return 0.25; } } // Implementing it is optional
    public decimal DeclareTaxes()
    {
        decimal taxesToPay = 4000 * TaxPercent;
        return taxesToPay;
    }
}

public sealed class BahamasBank: Bank
{
    public override string Country { get { return "Bahamas"; }
    public override TaxPercent { get { return 0.0; } } // Bahamas is different from most countries in tax related stuff
}

public sealed class CanadaBank: Bank
{
    public override string Country { get { return "Canada"; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following example is taken from Wikipedia (see **[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)**, C# section).

"C# does support method overriding, but only if explicitly requested using the modifiers `override` and **either `virtual` or `abstract`.** <sup>*)</sup>

```
abstract class Animal {
  public          String Name {get; set; }
  // Methods
  public          void   Drink() { Console.WriteLine("Animal drinks"); }
  public virtual  void   Eat() { Console.WriteLine("Animal eats"); }
  public abstract void   Go();
}

class Cat : Animal {
  public new      String Name {get; set; }
  // Methods
  public          void   Drink() { Console.WriteLine("Cat drinks"); } // warning: hides inherited Drink(). Use new
  public override void   Eat() { Console.WriteLine("Cat eats"); }   // overrides inherited Eat().
  public new      void   Go() { Console.WriteLine("Cat goes"); }    // hides inherited abstract Go(). Error - use override instead!
}
```

When overriding one method with another, the signatures of the two methods must be identical (and with same visibility). In C#, class methods, indexers, properties and events can all be overridden."

Note that

- in the example above for each not marked abstract, extern or partial function you need to declare a body (see CS0501 compiler message).
- In case of the `Go()` method you need to use `override` instead of `new`, because in the `abstract class Animal` `Go()` is declared as `abstract`. You will get a compiler error otherwise.
- For `Drink()` you should use the modifier `new`, because it hides Animal's `Drink` method. The compiler does not enforce this, but it will show a warning (assuming you meant to use `new`).

After you've made the corrections discussed, this code will call the 3 methods declared in the `Cat` class:

```
 var oCat = new Cat();
 oCat.Drink(); oCat.Eat(); oCat.Go();
```

and it will output

> Cat drinks
>
> Cat eats
>
> Cat goes

---

<sup>*)</sup> As [bradbury9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2265446/bradbury9) mentioned correctly, the Wikipedia page has an error, so I changed the answer slightly (added the text in bold above and fixed some C# syntax errors that exist in the Wikipedia article)

Comment: That wiki quote is wrong. It is true that it must be explicitly declared, but it should read " and `virtual` or `abstract`". As it is, it is missing the `abstract` keyword. I would suggest you editing the wiki and your answer or changing your link to MS reference.

Comment: @bradbury9 - Thanks for the hint, you are absolutely right. I changed the answer and added a footnote. Also, I updated the Wikipedia text.